# A suitable constructor of type does not be located

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am trying the most simple `IHttpClientFactory` use case

```
public interface IWeatherForecast
{
    Task<string> Get();
}

class WeatherForecast : IWeatherForecast
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    public WeatherForecast (IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://testwebapiforuseinsamples.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast");
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

and then instantiate it

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new ServiceCollection();
    container.AddHttpClient<IWeatherForecast, WeatherForecast>();
    var serviceProvider = container.BuildServiceProvider();    
    var resp = await serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherForecast>().Get();
}
```

However when I run it, it throws

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A suitable constructor for type 'HttpClientFactoryExample.WeatherForecast' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete ...

Can someone point it what is wrong with this code. I was expecting that after adding `WeatherForecast` service to DI, I will be able to get an initialized instance of it from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the type client registration that takes an abstraction like you did here

```
//...

container.AddHttpClient<IWeatherForecast, WeatherForecast>();

//...
```

it registers the abstraction as the client type, not the implementation.

> Adds the `IHttpClientFactory` and related services to the `IServiceCollection` and configures a binding between the `TClient` type and a named `HttpClient`. The client name will be set to the type name of `TClient`.

Reference [`IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions_AddHttpClient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_)

Because you try to resolve the implementation `WeatherForecast`

```
//...

var resp = await serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<WeatherForecast>().Get();

//...
```

it will fail because

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'WeatherForecast' has been registered.

What you should have actually resolved was the abstraction `IWeatherForecast`

```
//...

var resp = await serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWeatherForecast>().Get();

//...
```

which the container knows is mapped to the  `WeatherForecast` implementation and will then initialize it along with its dependencies.

With that fixed, you also need to update the service to explicitly depend on `HttpClient` since this is a typed client registration

```
class WeatherForecast : IWeatherForecast {
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public WeatherForecast (HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> Get() {
        var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://testwebapiforuseinsamples.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast");
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Reference [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Answer (score 7):

When you register type in Service collection as HTTP client `container.AddHttpClient<IWeatherForecast, WeatherForecast>()`, it MUST contains `HttpClient` in constructor. In your case it should be:

```
public WeatherForecast(HttpClient httpClient)
{
     this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Another option is to register separately the `HttpClientFactory` and your `WeatherForecast` service:

```
container.AddHttpClient();
container.AddTransient<IWeatherForecast, WeatherForecast>();
```

and then use the service with HttpClientFactory:

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

public WeatherForecast(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    this.httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this  works too. But I could accept only one answer.